# Changing single switch to double switch

Tags: electrical

I have a light switch in the bathroom that powers both the light and the fan.  I purchased a double switch so I can have 1 switch for the light and 1 switch for the fan.
I located the hot wire and the 2 load wires.  Hooked them up based on multiple instructional videos. The top switch does nothing and the bottom switch turns on both the light and fan still.

I have 3 lines coming into the box.  There is only 1 hot wire.  I am stuck.  Your help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Did you open the fan/light to see if it was connected with more than one cable?

Comment: Your new switch might not have a tab connecting the two "hot" terminals. Include a picture of both sides of your new switch. You probably have the terminals mixed up.

Comment: You don't have 1 hot wire & 2 load wires. You have 1 load wire, 1 incoming hot wire, and 1 outgoing hot wire which is supposed to be powering some other set or lights or outlets downstream elsewhere in the house. Leave the switches off and go looking in the room(s) nextdoor for stuff that no longer works.

Comment: Thank you.  The outgoing hot wire was leading to a hallway light.  Looks like the light and the fan will need to be run separately to the switch which means I need to run more line from the basement.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is common to feed both the light and fan from the same switch, so you have the feeder from the panel, one to the light/ fan and the 3rd is to another outlet or light. To figure out what it is disconnect the hot and find the device that is no longer functioning.